# Javascript code to get back to the same page when click the cancel button

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript code to expand and collapse my div contents.The follwing are my code.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .gap
    {

     border:1px solid black

    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);

           if(e.style.display == 'none')
              e.style.display = 'block';

           else
              e.style.display = 'none';

        }

        function edit(id,item)
        {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           var f = document.getElementById(item)

          e.innerHTML=f.innerHTML;

        }

    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1');" ><div class="gap">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</div></a>
<div id="id1" style="display:none;">This is foo</div>

 <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');" ><div class="gap">Click here to see      wonder</div></a>
<div id="id2" style="display:none;">Tsdgdfsehd
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit('id2','id3');">Edit</a></div>
</div>

    <div id="id3" style="display:none;">Edit
    <div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit('id3','id2');">cancel</a></div>

    </div>
```

The problem I am facing is..when I click the second div,It is expanding and I have given a edit option inside the 2nd div..and click the edit it is overriding the second div elements and displaying the 3rd div element.
The same way,In the 3rd div I have given the link for cancel the edit section and to display the 2nd div contents..but it is not displaying..

I am waiting for help..

Thanks In advance

Comment: Added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GfL7L/ here, I can't actually see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
location.reload();
```

Use the following function on cancel click

```
function cancel(){
       location.reload(); 
}

<a href="#"  onclick="cancel()">cancel</a>
```

Use the following for realoding div 2

```
function edit(id,item)
 {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var f = document.getElementById(item);
          // Add this line additional
    document.getElementById('id4').innerHTML=e.innerHTML;
    e.innerHTML=f.innerHTML;
  }
function cancel(){
    document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML=document.getElementById('id4').innerHTML;
}

 <a href="#"  onclick="cancel()">cancel</a>
```

also add this hidden div

```
<div id="id4" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: @Nithish..If I use the above code..the whole page will be reloaded..I wan to reload only the 2nd div content..

Comment: @bhai.. Is it ok with adding one more hidden div for achieving this?

Comment: @Nithish..Yes..any way I want to revert back to the 2nd div when I cancel the button..

Comment: @bhai. I done this with an etxra hidden div . any way will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

on cancel call a javascript function containing:

```
window.location=window.location;
```

Comment: This will reload the entire page which is less than ideal as a way to fix a click event.

Comment: @Zaheer..When I click the cancel button it should replace the 2nd div..but it is not happening when I use the above code

Comment: So it should revert the state back to having Edit as an active link and cancel as inactive?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way ,i find in your code

**onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');**

```
 <div id="id3" style="display:none;">Edit
 <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');">cancel</a></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: added another one answer for you try it

Answer (score 0):

your solution is here

check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfL7L/2/)

```
 <%-- 
Document   : ul
Created on : Jun 18, 2013, 10:23:01 AM
Author     : Genesh
 --%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>JSP Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.gap
{

 border:1px solid black

}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);

       if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';

       else
          e.style.display = 'none';

    }

    function edit(id,item)
    {
          var e = document.getElementById(id);
          e.style.display = 'block';
           var s = document.getElementById(item);
          s.style.display = 'none';
    }
       function edit1(id,item)
    {
          var e = document.getElementById(id);
          e.style.display = 'block';
      var s = document.getElementById(item);
          s.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1');" ><div class="gap">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</div></a>
 <div id="id1" style="display:none;">This is foo</div>

  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');" ><div class="gap">Click here to see      wonder</div></a>
 <div id="id2" style="display:none;">Tsdgdfsehd
 <div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit('id3','id2');">Edit</a></div>
 </div>
<div id="id3" style="display:none;">Edit
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit1('id2','id3');">cancel</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ganesh..Thanks..your code worked..and now it is reverting back to the 2nd div..thanks once again for helping me..